# Air for iOS "Device Error: Please check if there is enough space on the device."

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, ipa

So I have encountered this error. One day everything works fine, the other I can't upload the ipa to my iPad from Flash Pro CS6. Obviously I have checked there's enough space in the device.

iPhone utility explorer reports the error "A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted." when trying to install the ipa file. iTunes won't install the app either.

There are no strange characters in the app name.

I have redownloaded the profiles from Apple's portal and checked there were no problems with the app identifier, app name, etc. Flash gives this same error message when there's a problem with that.

I have changed the version number.

I checked the ipa file from terminal but didn't say anything useful.

```
codesign -vv /path/to/file.ipa
```

I have rebooted my ipad and installed latest software update.

Older ipa files upload fine from iPhone utility.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I packed a file in the ipa with a non valid character called "Ñ.png".

It's strange because Unix supports latin characters in file and folder names... anyway renaming that file put everything back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Same error here.
I think incorrect App ID cause this.
Fix it by reselect the provisioning profile.
It will set App ID correct.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that error a few times and it always takes me a while, complaining against multiple provision profile and certificate, before I remember that

it actually comes from the xml used to generate the ipa file.

Typically when you have a different xml for development and for distribution (if you're using Push in my case)