# Adobe AIR for iOS - device does not have enough space

Tags: ios, flash, air, adobe

I need to install a flash file using adobe air for ios on my iPhone.

I know of this link here that had a similar problem with the same error message
[air-for-ios-device-error-please-check-if-there-is-enough-space-on-the-device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178289/air-for-ios-device-error-please-check-if-there-is-enough-space-on-the-device)

But here is my issue, I have created an empty document, nothing in it and created the certificates and provisional profiles in my apple developer portal and it keeps giving the message "device error: please check if there is enough space on the device"

I have over 3Gb free on my device, so I am not sure why it is saying that.
Is there anything else I need to check or do especially?
I have done direct testing and created ad0hoc files and nothing works.

Any tips would be great, in the mean time I will keep googling, but no luck as yet.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed the issue - I re-created the .p12 certificates and it worked. Not sure why it didn't the first time.

I am not sure about the moderators for the forum, but maybe this could be turned into a protected post where people can post their issues and help each other rather than creating more posts on this same topic??